# Qual a diferença entre char (*ptr)[20] e char *ptr[20]?

Tags: c, array, ponteiro, matriz, declaração-de-variável

Estou estudando ponteiros e me deparei com essas declarações, mas não consegui entender muito bem. Poderiam me ajudar? Obrigado.

Comment: `char (*ptr)[20]` é um ponteiro para um array de 20 `char` e `char *ptr[20]` é um array de 20 ponteiros para `char`. Se com essa explicação, você conseguiu entender a diferença entre uma coisa e outra, então, talvez a sua dificuldade seja somente a leitura das instruções em C, recomendo pesquisar a "right-left rule". Por outro lado, se não conseguiu visualizar a diferença entre uma coisa e outra, isso exigiria um estudo mais aprofundado sobre ponteiros.

Comment: @v. Santos, coloque seu comentário como resposta

Comment: @zentrunix, eu pensei nisso, mas o meu problema é que o meu comentário me parece incompleto para uma resposta. E, para responder, eu não sabia se eu explicava a "right-left rule" ou se falava da diferença entre um ponteiro para um array  e um array de ponteiro. Agora, como quem fez a pergunta não se manifestou e como eu gostei da resposta dada por outro usuário, imagino que não exista mais essa necessidade de eu transformar o comentário em uma resposta. De todo modo, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde,

char (*ptr)[20] é um ponteiro para um array de 20 caracteres...um unico ponteiro que leva até uma "string"(char[20]), para simplificar.
Ex:

`*ptr -> "exemplo`"

Já char *ptr[20] é um array de 20 ponteiros...Você tem 20 ponteiros que apontam para caracteres.
Ex:

```
*ptr[0] -> e
*ptr[1] -> x
*ptr[2] -> e
*ptr[3] -> m
*ptr[4] -> p
*ptr[5] -> l
*ptr[6] -> o
```